# Git SSH Key for AWS OPS WORKS

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, ssh

I am trying to deploy a PHP app from Aws OpsWorks using GIT private repository

I have generated a SSH key and added a deploying key in git and pasted the same SSH key in AWS OpsWorks Application setting

I am getting this error, i am new to Git and AWS

[image]

Comment: You need to add the private key there. That seems to be the public key. Check Step 3 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-deploykeys.html

Comment: where can i get the private key, is there any procedure to generate  private key @MarcellFülöp

Comment: Keys can only be generated in pairs. A private and a public. They belong together.

Comment: The Git deploy key should be the public key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the private key there. That seems to be the public key. Check Step 3 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-deploykeys.html

SSH keys are generated in pairs, a private and a public. On a Debian distro like Ubuntu, you will find the keys under `/home/youruser/.ssh/` folder. `id_rsa` holds the private and `id_rsa.pub` the public key. Copy the contents of the `id_rsa` file and paste it into the Repository SSH Key field.

Comment: Awesome @MarcellFülöp thanq for your hint . . . another small doubt pls. . . shall i add public or private key in git's deploying key ??

Comment: The Git deploy key should be the public key.